# Comparing two dataframe values in python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, compare

I have two dataframes `df1['LicId']` and `df2['LicId']`.

`df1['LicId']` will always have one value

```
    LicId
0   abc1234
```

However `df2['LicId']` will have several Ids

```
    LicId
0   abc1234
1   xyz2345
```

My task is to compare `df1['LicId']` with `df2['LicId']` and execute the code only if there is a match between two.

I have tried:

```
if df1['LicId'][0]==df2['LicId'][0]:
    remaining code
```

However, this will check only for `abc1234` - It has to check for all the Index values of `df2`. Later, I may also have `xyz2345` in df1.

Can someone let me know how to handle this?

Comment: Sorry but your question is very poorly worded. I have no idea what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry about that - How to compare the value of one dataframe with the values of other dataframe? I have to execute my code only these two values are equal.

Comment: Can you post samples of your dataframes along with the desired output?

Comment: if df2 is relatively small in size, you can just check `if df1.LicId[0] in df2.LicId.values: ...`, or just use *merge*: `if len(df1.merge(df2)): ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match values with `isin()`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'LicId':['abc1234', 'a', 'b']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'LicId':['abc1234', 'xyz2345', 'a', 'c']})
```

`df1`:

```
     LicId
0  abc1234
1        a
2        b
```

`df2`:

```
     LicId
0  abc1234
1  xyz2345
2        a
3        c
```

Matching values:

```
if len(df2.loc[df2['LicId'].isin(df1['LicId'])]) > 0:
    print(df2.loc[df2['LicId'].isin(df1['LicId'])])
    #remaining code
```

Output:

```
     LicId
0  abc1234
2        a
```

Comment: As a side note `isin` will require both index & column labels matching for dataframe